# What is Adamarshana Sukhtam? Where is it from?

Tags: mantras, reference-request

I am unable to find any information of this Mantra. All I can get is it’s called the Adamarshana Sukhtam.

I came across this video on YouTube.

Sorry, I am also unable to find any lyrics anywhere.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Tm0TIh_aVeg&pp=ygUSYWRhbWFyc2hhbmEgc3VrdGFt

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the name *Adamarshana Suktam* is not used very commonly when referring to this mantra, but I found [this pdf](https://www.prapatti.com/slokas/english/aghamarshanasuuktam.pdf) that has it in its entirety. Here is the part that is rendered in your video:

It is taken from the Mahanarayana Upanishad (verse 67), though I've also seen [some sources](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Primer_of_Spirituality/GCJGEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22aham%20eva%22%20svaha&pg=PT187&printsec=frontcover) claim that it's from the Taittiriya Aranayaka, though I haven't been able to find it in the text.

> आर्द्रं ज्वलति ज्योतिरहमस्मि ज्योतिर्ज्वलति ब्रह्माहमस्मि।
> योऽहमस्मि ब्रह्माहमस्मि। अहमस्मि ब्रह्माहमस्मि। अहमेवाहं मां जुहोमि स्वाहा॥
>
> ārdraṁ jvalati jyotirahamasmi jyotirjvalati brahmāhamasmi |
> yo'hamasmi brahmāhamasmi |
> ahamasmi brahmāhamasmi |
> ahamevāhaṁ māṁ juhomi svāhā ||
>
> *That Supreme light which projected itself as the universe like a soaked seed which sprouts (or that Supreme light which shines as the substratum of the liquid element)—I am that Supreme light. I am that Supreme light of Brahman which shines (as the inmost essence of all that exists).*
>
> (In reality) I am the same infinite Brahman (even when I am experiencing myself as finite Self owing to ignorance).
> (Now by the onset of knowledge) I am really that Brahman which is my eternal nature.

Comment: I finally found an English translation of that particular section of the Suktam. yo'ham-asmi brahma-aham-asmi, aham-asmi brahma-aham-asmi, aham-

evAhaM mAM juhomi svAhA …..*

 

Whatever I am, I am Brahman, I am that Brahman, I am that I, May

the (little) i be consumed (in the big I) …….

Comment: @PJai - nice! I've added a translation+interpretation to my answer as well.